# React pass isLoggedIn useState from Login component to app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

I have a useState called isloggedIn in my App.js

I want to pass the **isLoggedIn** to Login component and after authentication set the value of isLoggedIn.

My Login component:

```
function Login(props) {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const history                 = useHistory();
    
    // Handle Login
    const handleLogin = async (e) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const adminData = {username, password};
        const response = await axios.post(
            "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/v1/login",
            adminData
        );
        if(response.data.error === "false"){
            //want to set the value of is logged in here
            history.push("/Admin/Dashboard");
        }else if(response.data.error === "true"){
            alert("Username or password is wrong")
        }
    };
    return(.......LOGIN FORM......)
 }
```

My App.js

```
function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <Router>
        <div className="App">
          {/* Navbar */}
          <Navbar/>
          

          {/* Pages */}
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact                     component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/about"                      component={About}/>
            <Route path="/contact"                    component={Contact}/>

            {/* Admin Pages */}
            <Route path="/Admin/Login" exact          component={Login}/>
            <ProtectedRoute path="/Admin/Dashboard"   component={Dashboard} isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}/>

            {/*404 Not Found Page*/}
            <Route path="*"                           component={Page404} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
    
  );
}
```

My protectedroute.js requires isLoggedIn to render some protected routes

**Extra question**
I have a lot of menus for admin dashboard. Will all the routes for the menus go inside App.js like other routes? Or will they be handled ny Admin Dashboard?
I'll be using material-ui drawer for my dash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a render prop to the Route. This would allow the passing of props to the component you wish to render.

```
<Route
  path='/login'
  render={(props) => (
    <Login {...props} isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
  )}
```

I am assuming you are using React router v4 as you have not mentioned in the question.
For more information, you can refer the blog https://ui.dev/react-router-v4-pass-props-to-components.
Make sure to spread the props as all other props also needs to be passed to the Login Component (eg: history)

Comment: And how would I set the value of isLoggedIn inside login component?

Comment: you can access the value of isLoggedIn as props.isLoggedIn

Comment: I tried props.isLoggedIn(true) but it gives me "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): props.isLoggedIn is not a function"

Comment: I had to do this: <Login setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn}/> 
Can you explain why (...rest) didn't work when setIsLogged in worked?

Comment: props.isLoggedin is a state value not a function.whereas setIsLoggedIn is a function. If you require to pass a function , it needs to be explicity passed until and unless it is in props.,